# Context and dependency injection (CDI) 1.2 and Dynamic Web Module 3.0 cannot both be selected?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, cdi

I don't know what I touched on my maven project... but I have this error on problems view

Description 
Context and dependency injection (CDI) 1.2 and Dynamic Web Module 3.0 cannot both be selected.
Resource
wfadm-rest
Location
line 1
Type
Maven Java EE Configuration Problem

In Project Facets "Context and dependency injection (CDI)" is not selected at all...

What I can look?

Answer (score 0):

Update your JAX RS from 1.0 to 2.1 or upper. Its solve my error.

[image]